# Android Studio Gradle Build Error: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFreeDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, gradle, ionic4, capacitor, ionic-vue

Then on building or launhcing on my device i get following error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFreeDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:freeDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :capacitor-android.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :capacitor-android was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'minApi' with value '____free', attribute 'tier' with value 'free', attribute 'abi' with value 'x86' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

It is building my project using grable.

I have tried Build Clean, Build Rebuild and File > Invlaidate Caches and Resatrt as well.

Kindly help.

Comment: Hi Piyush, do you remember what solved this problem for you? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing jetifier solved my error
by executing `npm install jetifier`

Jetifier tool migrates support-library-dependent libraries to rely on the equivalent AndroidX package

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, in my case the android folder was generated in wsl and copied in a windows folder to build the apk with android studio, is necesary the node_modules folder because android project have a reference to ../node_modules/@capacitor/.....

You can copy the node_modules or just the package.json and run npm install

The android and node_modules folder need to be at the same level